# laravel current timestamp in migration with carbon

Tags: laravel, timestamp, migration, php-carbon

I want to display created_at as a timestamp like this :

`created_at : 1625501162`

so this is my created_at column in migration:

`$table->string('created_at')->Carbon::now()->timestamp;`

Now I want this field to be created automatically when a new record is created and record the current time. so when i change the line to this :

`$table->string('created_at')->useCurrent(Carbon::now()->timestamp);`

gives me this error :

`Method call is provided 1 parameters, but the method signature uses 0 parameters`

so how can i fix this problem?

What other ways do you suggest for timestamp created_at and store it automatically?

Comment: by default `created_at` column automatically filled by model with current timestamp, so you don't need to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your column to be a timestamp you should use `timestamp()` instead of `string()`. `useCurrent()` doesn't take a parameter. Change

```
$table->string('created_at')->useCurrent(Carbon::now()->timestamp);
```

to

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-timestamp

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers

Edit: to always get a timestamp instead of a date you can use

```
protected $casts = ['created_at' => 'timestamp'];
```

in your Model.

Comment: but this code returns this : `2021-07-29 14:07:29` i want created_at like this : `1627552004`

Comment: Returns where? What is stored in your database? It most likely returns a date because `created_at` is cast as date. You can cast to timestamp using `protected $casts = ['created_at' => 'timestamp'];` in your controller. See if that works

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi:Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable –

Answer (score 3):

Instead of string you may use `timestamp()` in your migration.

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
```

Also you may use casting inside model to always get expected format when receiving model.

```
class Something extends Model {
    protected $cast = [
        'created_at' => 'timestamp'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to [configure the date format](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps) of the model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}
```

No need to put a default value in the migration. everytime created_at, updated_at and deleted_at(if you use soft delete) is to be updated/filled, it will be in a unix timestamp format

Migration should be an integer

```
$table->integer('created_at')->nullable(); //you can omit this nullable
$table->integer('updated_at')->nullable(); //you can omit this nullable

// if you use softDelete trait
$table->integer('deleted_at')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a column createdAt. When a new record is created, it defaults to the date in UNIX format.

```
$table->integer('createdAt')->default(DB::raw('extract(epoch from now())'));
```